# MYSQL: 1 duplicated result per hour

Tags: mysql

I am creating a "Hour by Hour" report which shows number of users logged into a system each hour, i want this to be a distinct count.

However when i run the below SQL it is adding and additional 1 in each other for example if 12am = 5 when the true figure is 4, 1am = 10 when the true figure is 9.

I cant work out why this is happening. there is a link below which shows you how my results look which is fine however it's showing incorrect info.

Below is my query.

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 00:59:59',
       (Userid),
        0)) AS '12am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 01:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 01:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '1am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 02:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 02:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '2am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 03:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 03:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '3am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 04:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 04:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '4am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 05:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 05:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '5am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 06:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 06:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '6am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 07:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 07:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '7am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 08:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 08:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '8am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 09:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 09:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '9am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 10:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 10:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '10am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 11:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 11:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '11am',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 12:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 12:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '12pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 13:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 13:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '1pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 14:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 14:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '2pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 15:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 15:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '3pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 16:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 16:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '4pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 17:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 17:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '5pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 18:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 18:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '6pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 19:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 19:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '7pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 20:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 20:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '8pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 21:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 21:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '9pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 22:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 22:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '10pm',
    count(distinct IF(loginDate BETWEEN '2017-02-08 23:00:00' AND '2017-02-08 23:59:59',
        (Userid),
        0)) AS '11pm'
FROM
    mb_useraccessheader
```

[Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu51q.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of your `If` condition. You are saying `distinct (If(true,userid,0))` . Since `0` is a value it counts as a `distinct` value.

Solution : Replace it with `null`